# Remove index.php from url code is not working in codeigniter in Godaddy Plesk hosting?

Tags: codeigniter

I have tried with following code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I have replaced with blank in config file index_page but still not working and getting this error.

```
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Please help me to sort out this.

Comment: What version of codeigniter you using and what operating system?

Comment: I am using 2.2 and windows 7. All is working fine on previous server but when i moved on new server then this problem is coming.

Comment: This may help https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter Also in some cases you may need to have the first letter of file names of controllers and models and class name as upper case as in codeigniter 3 I am not sure about it in codeigniter 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove index.php in Wamp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208746/how-to-remove-index-php-in-wamp)

Comment: How i can check rewrite_module is enabled or not?

Comment: check this [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021425/how-to-check-if-mod-rewrite-is-enabled-in-php)

Comment: i have checked phpinfo() but no apache configuration showing.

Comment: @Shalu any live url to check this out??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have solved the problem. I have made web.config in root directory of codeigniter. My Code is following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite> 
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It is working for me. I hope this will help others too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Working as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

place your `.htaccess` file within your codeiginter project directory then write this code in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|[Javascript / CSS / Image root Folder name(s)]|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project_dir_name/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Replace "project_dir_name" with you actual directory name in 3rd line.

If still you have problem then check your controller, method name and permission of folders and files.

Comment: It is on plesk server of go-daddy. I have tried all codes and changes but nothing work.

Comment: have you changed 'base_ur' in config/config.php file ?

Comment: Yes, I have changed base_url to with domain name